# How to print a Crystal Report ReportClientDocument to postscript file

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I'm trying to get a postscript file from a Crystal Report. In the past we were using this method in order to obtain the postscript:

```
            var printer = "Solomon PostScript Printer";
            if (parameters != null) {
                foreach (var pair in parameters) {
                    report.SetParameterValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                }
            }
            report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printer;
            var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings {
                PrinterName = printer,
                PrintToFile = true,
                PrintFileName = fileName
            };
            var pageSettings = new PageSettings(printerSettings);

            report.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pageSettings, false);
            Task.Delay(400).Wait();
            return File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

This seems to work, but the PDF does have the desired  quality. I have been trying this new method of printing Crystal Reports, using the ReportClientDocument object:

```
            var printer = "Solomon PostScriptPrinter";
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.PrintReportOptions popt = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.PrintReportOptions();
            popt.PrinterName = printer;
            report.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(popt);
            Task.Delay(400).Wait();
            return File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

However when we print this way,  I can't seem to get it to print to file, like we were before, it brings up a Save As dialog and makes you enter a file name. This method produces a much higher quality PDF, and it would be great if there was a way to make it print to file without bringing up any windows or dialogs. Any suggestions? Thanks.